# Join 2 tables by order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

This is in SQL Server. I have two tables below:

Table A

```
EVENTID  CID    QID
-----------------------
1953     4104   Q900068
1954     4104   Q900068
1955     4104   Q900068
```

Table B

```
EVENTID   CID     IRR
----------------------------
2772      5384    Q900068IRR
2773      5384    Q900068IRR
2837      5384    Q900068IRR
```

How can I get a result like below by SQL? (The min A.EVENTID is mapping the min B.EVENTID, and the  max A.EVENTID is mapping the max B.EVENTID and the middle A.EVENTID is mapping the middle B.EVENTID). QID is a substring of IRR.

```
1953    4104    Q900068 2772    5384    Q900068IRR
1954    4104    Q900068 2773    5384    Q900068IRR
1955    4104    Q900068 2837    5384    Q900068IRR
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you will always have exactly the same number of rows in table A and table B? Can you please tag with the actual type of SQL (SQL Server? Oracle? MS Access?)

Comment: Yes. Table A and B always have exactly the same number of rows.  The database server is SQL SERVER 2017. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
   SELECT A.EVENTID,A.CID,A.QID,B.EVENTID,B.CID,B.IRR FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EVENTID ASC) ROWNO,EVENTID,CID,QID 
        FROM A
    )A
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EVENTID ASC) ROWNO,EVENTID,CID,IRR 
        FROM B
    )B ON A.ROWNO=B.ROWNO
```

Comment: This is correct as we use a column like line number to match 1:1 each table

Comment: Many thanks Atique Rahman! Your solution is wonderful! A good lesson about how to use row_number. Thanks again!